# What are the pros and cons of resistive and capacitive touchscreen mobile devices?

Tags: mobile, touchscreen

I have zeroed it down to these two phones [Nokia X6 and Nokia C6](http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=2922&idPhone2=3229).

Apart from others, one difference is the presence of capacitive touchscreen in one and resistive in the other.

If I were to decide only on the basis of these touchscreen technologies, which one should I go for?

Comment: I think this is off topic but I'm not 100%. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's not phrased as an electronics question, really, but could be useful to someone building a touch display.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=resistive+vs+capacitive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Capacitive:** Generally more expensive, can support "multi-touch", rely on skin contact because the persons electrical field is what causes changes.  This means they don't work well, or at all with gloves on.  Doesn't rely on touch pressure, so are generally more responsive to finger use/light taps, etc.  Requires a fairly complicated controller.

**Resistive:** Cheap, only a single touch point can be detected.  Rely on pressure to achieve detection (u may have to push hard on them).  Any object touching the screen can create a "press" event, so gloves, non-conductive pens, etc work fine.  Controller is very simple, just measures a few resistances.